# How to calculate a pdf of a random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-modeling, estimation

I'm reading a paper about kernel estimation and struggling with this part, which constructs the pdf of log`Z^2` (Z has Standard normal distribution)
I don't understand how they compute the function like this. Can someone provide the detailed computation from step 1 to step 2?
Many thanks in advance.

Let $f_Z$ denote the density of $\log Z_i^2$. We obtain,
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}}$
$\newcommand{\deriv} [2]   {{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2} }}$
\begin{align*}
  f_Z(x) 
    &= \deriv{}{x}\brp{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{e^{x/2}} e^{-s^2/2}ds-1}
  \\&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\brs{\brp{\deriv{}{x}e^{x/2}}e^{-e^x/2}}
  \\&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\brs{\frac{1}{2}e^{x/2}e^{-e^x/2}}
  \\&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{x/2}e^{-e^x/2}
\end{align*}

[1][function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEE98.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaKMB.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but reading it with my cell phone I cannot see your picture. That is one of the reason why it is not a good idea to substitute formulas with pictures.

Anyway, just using the Fundamental Transformation theorem, [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) in the paragraph "Functions of Random Variables, you will easy find that

$$y=\log z^2$$

$$z^2=e^y$$

$$|z|=e^{y/2}$$

and

$$\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}z\Bigg|=\frac{1}{2}e^{y/2}$$

thus

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-e^{y}/2}\frac{1}{2}e^{y/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-e^{y}/2}e^{y/2}$$

At present I cannot check if my result matches with yours but I think it does.